# In a database with shared/exclusive locks, when an UPDATE statement is executed at the beginning of the transaction, how do the locks work?

Tags: database, postgresql, concurrency, locks

In a database with shared/exclusive locks, when an UPDATE statement is executed at the beginning of the transaction, how do the locks work? Assuming Repeatable Read or higher, does it get a shared lock during the reading and searching stage and then an exclusive lock, or does it get an exclusive lock from the beginning? Assuming Read Committed, does an UPDATE statement get the exclusive lock only at the write stage, or does it get it as soon as it starts to read? I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: I found http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_lock_types.htm for Oracle, so I am guessing that PostgreSQL will similarly only use an exclusive lock from the beginning of the execution of the UPDATE statement. In both cases, data access is not reduced due to MVCC. I am guessing that if shared locks were used during execution of UPDATE statements, the documentation would have mentioned it at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PostgreSQL scans the table for rows that meet the `WHERE` condition of the `UPDATE`, it doesn't lock rows at all. Only when a candidate row is found, it locks it in `EXCLUSIVE` mode. If the lock cannot be acquired right away, and the `UPDATE` is blocked, PostgreSQL waits until it can get the lock and then reads the row again. The behavior depends on the isolation level:

- with `READ COMMITTED`, if the latest row version still satisfies the `WHERE` condition, it is locked
- with `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE`, if the row has changed, you get a serialization error and have to retry the transaction

All this [is well documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html).